# Laravel eager loading nested relationships with custom query

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eager-loading

I have the code which works, but without eager loading nested relationships.

```
$projects = Project::with('organization')
        ->leftJoin('stages', 'stages.project_id', '=', 'projects.id')
        ->leftJoin('activities', 'activities.stage_id', '=', 'stages.id')
        ->leftJoin('tasks', 'tasks.activity_id', '=', 'activities.id')
        ->select('projects.*',  DB::raw('SUM(IF(tasks.status = 4, score, 0)) AS score'), 
                                DB::raw('SUM(tasks.score) AS total_score'))
        ->groupBy('projects.id')
        ->get();
```

I want to do this with eager loading nested relationships, and if I wouldn't have these custom selects (total_score and score), I would do

```
$projects = Project::with('stages.activities.tasks');
```

but the problem appears on those custom selects (score and total_score).
I tried something like that, but didn't work

```
$projects = Project::with(['stages', 'activities', 'tasks' => function($q) { 
        $q->select( DB::raw('SUM(IF(tasks.status = 4, score, 0)) AS score'), 
                    DB::raw('SUM(tasks.score) AS total_score')); 
    }])->get();
```

Comment: How would the SQL of this ideally look like?  If I'm understanding your question right, it may be more efficient to do this as 2 queries

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like that should work:

```
$projects = $project::with(array('stages' => function($q)
 {
   $q->with(array('activities' => function($q)
   {
     $q->with(array('tasks' => function($q)
     {
        $q->groupBy('tasks.id');
        $q->addselect([
            DB::raw('SUM(IF(tasks.status = 4, score, 0)) AS score'),
            DB::raw('SUM(tasks.score) AS total_score')
            ]);
       }));
     }));
   }))
 ->get();
```

If you need more argument to your function `function($q) use ($arg)`.